# Remove all classes of children elements within div and add class to clicked div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following:

(I've removed all other code and only included the relevant bit)

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Main() {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="nav">
        <Link to="/"><div id="one" class="active"></div></Link>
        <Link to="/"><div id="two"></div></Link>
        <Link to="/"><div id="three"></div></Link>
        <Link to="/"><div id="four"></div></Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

What I want is when the user clicks on, for example, `<div id="two">`, the active class is removed from `<div id="one">` and added to two.

Comment: Seems that you are trying to show the current active link with a specific class, maybe this can help since you are using react-router-dom https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/tutorial#active-links

Comment: @Woohaik thank you, I'll read through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) component, several of its props can consume a callback function that is passed an `isActive` property.

> ```
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

Use the `children` function prop that accepts an `isActive` property that can be used to conditionally apply CSS/logic/etc to a child component.

Example:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<NavLink to="/" end> // <-- end prop to match "/" when not on sub-route
  {({ isActive }) => (
    <div
      id="one"
      class={isActive ? "active" : ""}
    >
    </div>
  )}
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/">
  {({ isActive }) => (
    <div
      id="two"
      class={isActive ? "active" : ""}
    >
    </div>
  )}
</NavLink>
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I started learning React literally less than a week ago lol, I know there's a lot that React encompasses, so far the hardest part is just finding these built in functions

Comment: @JustinRiley No worries. I spent about the first 2 years working with React reading and rereading, and rereading, React and common associated libraries' docs almost daily. They are a great resource. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Hey, follow up: how can I prevent the "home" div from staying active? i.e the home link is ```<NavLink to="/"><div id="one"></div></NavLink>``` and ```one``` stays active even when the other nav divs are clicked. The other divs work properly, they go active when clicked and active is removed when a different div is clicked, but "/" stays active.

Comment: @JustinRiley Use the `end` prop on that link. See the last section and example in the NavLink doc I linked in my answer.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you sir